# Order Sort Function Numerical and by Date

Tags: java, sorting

function that sets a list of folders in numeric order and then return such list in order of date created.

4_Lemur_Jason_20250814_Text

3_Lemur_Jason_20221025_Text

6_Lemur_Jason_20200510_Text

=

first list in numeric order

3_Lemur_Jason_20221025_Text

4_Lemur_Jason_20250814_Text

6_Lemur_Jason_20200510_Text

=

Second list in date created

6_Lemur_Jason_20200510_Text

3_Lemur_Jason_20221025_Text

4_Lemur_Jason_20250814_Text

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what the whole question is asking, though I believe you can use something like this to get/order the numbers from the file name:

```
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("its location"));
    
    // create first/default
    int smallest = Integer.parseInt(
        fileScanner.nextLine().substring(0, 1));
    
    while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        // reads only the digit
        int next = Integer.parseInt(
            fileScanner.nextLine().substring(0, 1));
        // replaces the digit if it's smaller
        smallest = (smallest > next) ? next : smallest; 
    }
```

Emphasis that this is not a full solution as I am not quite sure what you are asking